# How to add Eclipse Task Tags programmatically (Eclipse Plugin development)?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, task, markers

I am developing an Eclipse Plugin. I want to add my custom Task Tag programmatically within the plugin. (Lets say DOTHIS) Later, i want to list the lines marked with DOTHIS tag in my custom taskView

I know that it is done using the Eclipse UI from Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Task Tags > New. and then in the task view by Configure Contents  but how can i do these arranegments within the plugin?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check code of 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.TodoTaskPreferencePage' and 'org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.TodoTaskConfigurationBlock.updateModel(DialogField) '  from  'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' UI plugin.